# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute analyze

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I was trying to calculate tf-idf and here is my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA

train_set = ["The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright."] #Documents
test_set = ["The sun in the sky is bright sun."] #Query
stopWords = stopwords.words('english')

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stopWords)
#print vectorizer
transformer = TfidfTransformer() 
#print transformer

trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
testVectorizerArray = vectorizer.transform(test_set).toarray()
print 'Fit Vectorizer to train set', trainVectorizerArray
print 'Transform Vectorizer to test set', testVectorizerArray

transformer.fit(trainVectorizerArray)
print
print transformer.transform(trainVectorizerArray).toarray()

transformer.fit(testVectorizerArray)
print
tfidf = transformer.transform(testVectorizerArray)
print tfidf.todense()
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tf-idf2.py", line 16, in <module>
trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 341,
in fit_transform
term_count_current = Counter(self.analyzer.analyze(doc))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'analyze'
```

I am using scikit version 0.14.1.

Comment: And what might the question be? :D

Comment: You are passing a list (with one string element) to the `.fit_transform` function. What does it expect?

Comment: if i do as @larsmans said below then i was getting this error 
  **Traceback (most recent call last): File "tf-idf2.py", line 11, in <module> vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopWords) TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stop_words'**

Answer (score 0):

```
CountVectorizer(stopWords)
```

should be

```
CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopWords)
```

Always use keyword arguments for the constructor parameters of scikit-learn objects, unless indicated otherwise in the docs.

Comment: if i do as directed then i am getting this error. **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf-idf2.py", line 11, in <module>
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopWords)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stop_words'**